# How to access variables of a child when doing a reference at an abstract class or interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, adapter

I'm learning coding patterns, and I'm having troubles learning the adapter pattern, since it uses liskov. What i don't understand is how to access a private variable from a child when referencing the abstract class or interface.

```
public class Aplication {

public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException {

    Input in;
    Output out;
    out=new PrintConsole();
    in= new ConsoleAdapter();
    ext.print(in.catch());  
}
```

This is my interface

```
public interface Input {

public void catch();}
```

And this is my child class

```
public class ConsoleAdapter implements Input{

InputConsole Input;
private int num;

public ConsoleAdapter() {

    Input=new ConsoleAdapter();
}

@Override
public void catch() {

    num=Input.cathInteger();

}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}
```

So with this, how could i call the var num from ConsoleAdapter in the main without using static variables?

Comment: The first question you have to ask yourself is: **why** do you want to access var `num`? If you can provide a good answer for this question, then your usage of the interface `Input` is not correct in this scenario (since it doesn't provide access to variable `num`).

Comment: Input interface only defines the method implemented for several ways of input, for example by console, by GUI, so in this program I want to adapt the input of a console catching string into integer and giving it to a calculator class. Like i don't want to have several methods for each type of  input, like double, float, string, int etc. So i said let's use a void so it can just modify the value of num in the consoleAdapter, I was trying to make a return method but i've got a problem, if i define it string, it will only return sting for every class that extends or implements the father class.

Answer (score 0):

Add getNum() method to your interface Input then you overrride it in the your ConsoleAdapter class or declare in as ConsoleAdapter.

Comment: if I declare in as ConsoleAdapter, it wouldn't use liskov, and it isn't the idea :(